# How do you update your github.io repo when changes are made on your local files?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I recently signed up to github pages so that I can host a website domain that I purchased. I created a repo adding my local files to the repo and redirected my github.io to my new domain that was purchased. Everything is working fine however, when I make changes to my local files how do I make these changes effective on my github also so that the changes would be reflected onto my website?

Comment: You make a commit and push to the remote. I'd recommend running though the basic tutorials on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Basic flow,

```
git add <changed filename>
git commit -m "Commit message, what are the changes"
git push
```

You should use branches if you are making changes to your live apps.
https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to commit and push your changes, and it will be live.

To commit your changes:

```
git add --all

git commit -m "Several changes"
```

Now just push to your branch:

```
git push -u origin your-branch

## Example: git push -u origin master
```